# Looping through subdirectories and deleting files that are duplicate md5 hashes

Tags: python, md5, subdirectory

I have a directory with a lot of subdirectories with txt files in these subdirs. For each subdirs, I want to get the md5 hashes of each file in the respective subdir and delete any duplicate md5 hashes in that subdirectory [Python].

I need help writing a function that takes in the directory and returns the directory without txt files that have duplicate md5 hashes by subdir.

Comment: did you try something that didnt work?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `os.listdir` to list a directory

you can use `os.path.join(BASEDIR,filename)` to get a path to the results

you can use `open(filename,"rb")` to open a file for reading(binary is aok)

you can use `filehandle.read` to get the bytes out of a file

you can use `hashlib.md5` to generate md5's (among other methods)

you would use a list/set/or dictionary to keep track of what you have already seen
(set or dict will be faster)

anything you have seen you would use `os.remove` in order to delete

this is one algorithm that you could use to solve the problem, there are plenty of other ways you could also solve this